# Tensorflow model training: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, tensorflow, model

I am trying to practice a neural network classifier following the example of [Train your first neural network: basic classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification), and here is my code till the point of model training:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from matplotlib.pyplot import colorbar
from matplotlib.pyplot import axis
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import show

print(tf.__version__)

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()


#figure(); imshow(train_images[1]); colorbar(); axis('auto') 

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

N1, N2, N3 = test_images.shape

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images  = test_images / 255.0

model = keras.Sequential
([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(N2, N3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
```

It returns error of

```
TypeError: _method_wrapper() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

which happens at

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I googled a little bit, seems

```
m = model()
m.compile()
```

can avoid the 'self' error. However, it gets new error that the training still does not happen.

I am just wondering how should I modified the code such that I can get the model to train like this:

```
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
32768/29515 [=================================] - 0s 0us/step
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
26427392/26421880 [==============================] - 1s 0us/step
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
8192/5148 [===============================================] - 0s 0us/step
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
4423680/4422102 [==============================] - 0s 0us/step
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some slight modifications to your code. Hope you could follow up. Instead of adding the layers inside of `Sequential()`, I just took everything out and added layer by layer to the `model`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from matplotlib.pyplot import colorbar
from matplotlib.pyplot import axis
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from matplotlib.pyplot import show

print(tf.__version__)

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()


#figure(); imshow(train_images[1]); colorbar(); axis('auto') 

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

N1, N2, N3 = test_images.shape

train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images  = test_images / 255.0
# model = Sequential
# ([
#     keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(N2, N3)),
#     keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
#     keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
# ])

model= Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(train_images.reshape(len(train_images),784), train_labels, epochs=5)
```

With this code it runs like below.

> 32/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 3:02 - loss: 2.6468 -
>   acc: 0
>
> 1344/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 6s - loss: 1.3037 -
>   acc: 0.5
>
> 2816/60000 [>.............................] - ETA: 4s - loss: 1.0207 -
>   acc: 0.6
>
> 4256/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 3s - loss: 0.9073 -
>   acc: 0.6
>
> 5632/60000 [=>............................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.8394 -
>   acc: 0.7
>
> 7104/60000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.7912 -
>   acc: 0.7

Comment: Thanks! So the default input shape for the fit function is always flat?

Comment: It's not always flat. Input to a Dense layer should be in the format of `(sample_size,flattened_image)` if an image is the input. The input should be 2 dimensional. For a Conv2d layer, you add another dimension.

Comment: OK. Thanks Avin.